# How to code "Next Friday" in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would have thought that `=TODAY() + (6 - WEEKDAY(TODAY()))` would work, but there is an bug in here somewhere.

The above still shows 5/21. (Previous Friday)

Thanks!

Comment: "Next Friday" is not clear. Do you mean "the next Friday after today" (e.g., if today is a Thursday, "next Friday" is tomorrow) or "Friday of next week" (e.g., if today is a Thursday, "next Friday" is 8 days from now)?  And if the latter, which day do you consider to be the first of the week: Sunday or Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a `switch` statement. Ugly, but it works

`=TODAY() + SWITCH(weekday(today()), 7,6,6,7,5,1,4,2,3,3,2,4,1,5)`

Comment: Thant is ugly! But it works! Lol. Would you perhaps care to explain how it works for us? I'm curious...

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following formula

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>6,11,6)
```

Functions used:

- [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)
- [`WEEKDAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)