# In Google Sheets, how can you return the next Friday from today, excluding today if today is Friday?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to return the next Friday *after* today in a cell in Google Sheets (format: "dddd d mmm yyyy")

I have used the following formula and this works when today is Monday-Friday but on a Saturday it returns the *second* next Friday after today instead.

=TEXT(TODAY() + MOD(6 - WEEKDAY(TODAY()), 7) + IF(weekDAY(TODAY()) >= 6, 7, 0), "dddd d mmm yyyy")

Can anyone help me solve this please (and let me know where the error is so I know for next time!)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to code "Next Friday" in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655230/how-to-code-next-friday-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the >= sign. Saturday is number 7, so you're adding an extra week after today. I'd change it to an equal

```
=TODAY() + MOD(6 - WEEKDAY(TODAY()), 7) + IF(weekDAY(TODAY()) >= 6, 7, 0)
=TODAY() + 6 + 7
```

Instead:

```
=TODAY() + MOD(6 - WEEKDAY(TODAY()), 7) + IF(weekDAY(TODAY()) = 6, 7, 0)
=TODAY() + 6 + 0
```